Custom constraints and custom cost function in mppi
I am currently working on implementing custom constraints and custom cost functions in the MPPI module of nav2. I would like to request guidance on the the same.
Objective: apply constraint on the yaw value such that it should not exceed beyond a permissble value

For cost function, we have critics in mppi. Can we modify those, if yes, Do we have any resource for that.
For implementation of custom constraints, which file I should explore.


You should create your own critic function, not modify existing ones. They're pluginlib plugins that are dynamically loaded at run-time so you can have external project-specific critics that can be loaded and used at runtime with Nav2 without forking or modifying any of Nav2's source code. See pluginlib docs for more information, but MPPI itself is a plugin of the Controller Server that you can use as reference (in addition to the other critics).
See MPPI & the critic files below.
https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_mppi_controller
https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_mppi_controller/src/critics
